# Response in alert view

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, uialertview

[image: empty value in alertview]I am new to IOS i want to display response from post in alert view.in nslog i showed response. i need when i clicked button alert view can display my response.

coding:

```
-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method params:(NSString *)str{


    NSData *postData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[str length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ){

        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
```

alerview:

```
- (IBAction)butt1:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Value"
                                                    message:@"%@"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];

    [self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:str];

    [alert show];

}
```

post method delegates:
here i get response in json111 that i showed in nslog successfully but in alert view i  failed

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [mutableData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    return;
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{


    NSError* error111;
   json111 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: mutableData
                                           options:kNilOptions
                                             error:&error111];
    NSLog(@"%@",json111);



}

 [![emptyvalue in alertview][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this into

**updated answer**

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> 


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{


NSError* error111;
json111 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: mutableData
                                       options:kNilOptions
                                         error:&error111];
NSLog(@"%@",json111);

NSArray *temp = [ json111 objectForKey:@"Currencies"];

 // you can directly fetch like
 NSDictionary *fetchDict = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
  NSDictionary *fetchUnit = [temp objectAtIndex:1];
 // finally you can fetch like
  NSString * total = [fetchDict objectForKey:@"total"];
   NSString * one_unit = [fetchUnit objectForKey:@"one_unit"];

  //updated
  NSString *final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ , %@", total,one_unit];

 // in here you can assign the value to Alert


UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Value"
                                                message:final
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];

 alert.tag = 100;
[alert show];


}




- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{ 
  if (alertView.tag == 100)
{
if (buttonIndex == 0)
 { 
  // ok button pressed
  //[self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:str];
}else
 {
   // cancel button pressed
}
}
```

Comment: uialertview is deprecated in iOS9, in this place use UIAlertviewController

Comment: i need response value from post method not textfield value @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @A.sonu oh Ice, just wait I modify my anser

Comment: @A.sonu - what the answer u get here NSLog(@"%@",json111);

Comment: 2016-05-09 13:21:04.356 exchange[1408:63679] {
    Currencies =     (
                {
            total = "0 USD B";
        },
                {
            "one_unit" = "1 USD B = 0.99203640500569 USD B";
        }
    );
}@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @in that resposnse what the value you want to show in alertview

Comment: that whole response i want in alert view @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111386/discussion-between-a-sonu-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: @A.sonu - check the updated answer , for understanding purpose i add simply

Comment: ya i checked but i  need both total and one_unit in alert view @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @A.sonu - simple , just wait

Comment: but based on user selection value can change its showing initial only @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: default its showing initial 0 value but i need according to user selection in textfield the value can change in alert view and display@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: when ever u get response the alert value will modify , but one scenario, your json response is wrong

Comment: i think so because i passed all id but it showing only one value @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: ya need @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @A.sonu -- mudiyala , ok show some response based on multiple IDs

Comment: i passed this id as parameter                                                                   2016-05-09 15:51:07.675 exchange[2001:108766] branch_id=1,2,3,4&from_curr=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35&to_curr=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35&value=(null)

@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: k in here you want to pass the value = 0 USD, 1 USD to server, correct or not

Comment: total response i got this2016-05-09 15:51:08.390 exchange[2001:108766] {
    Currencies =     (
                {
            total = "0 USD B";
        },
                {
            "one_unit" = "1 USD B = 0.99203640500569 USD B";
        }
    );
}
@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: no you need the final output like branch_id=1,2,3,4&from_curr=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,2‌​1,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35&to_curr=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13‌​,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35&value=0 USD, 1 USD , correct or wrong

Comment: sorry u confused i think so@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: k i tell u in clearly first thing just see screenshot for simulator which i posted and user want to select three textfield according to their wish  then their three textfield id can be "fetch" and four textfield for give any" value" for user finally  "fetch value " and  "user value" together passed in post method and lastly i click button its shows "response value" in alert view @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

You should know the basics of `NSString`, refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html).

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Value"
                                                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str]
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your response in an NSString and then pass this string in the message field of your alert view.

However, as of iOS 8,

> UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead

Answer (score 0):

Change your Alert View as following :

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Value"
                                                message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Response Message : %@",str]
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
```

This will display your response message instead %@..

If you want to send Data to Server on Click on alertView, you need to write code in alertView Delegate **clickedButtonAtIndex**

Hope it helps..